# iPhone: XML Parsing Problem?

Tags: iphone, xml, unicode, nsxmlparser

I have some XML that looks like the following sample:

```
<INLINE>
   <IMG LINKTEXT="خدمات ديني يقيني"  NUMOFCOLOUMNS="9" NUMOFROWS="20">RamadanPortal</IMG>
</INLINE>
```

When I tried to parse the above XML using `NSXMLParser`, I'm getting the `LINKTEXT` response as `U062e\U062f`.

How can I get the exact Arabic text instead of Unicode characters? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the file in the correct encoding.  There's plenty of documentation on this on the apple website (developer docs), but since you haven't supplied a code example I can't point you at the exact one.

Comment: i have  downloaded the xml file with NSUTF8encoding

Comment: What was the xml file originally encoded in?  it should say near the top.  Each xml file can have a different encoding.

Comment: this is the xml im downloading utf8encoding<PAGE CUSTOMIZE="False">
<CONTENT>
<DATA>
<SITEINFO BACKGROUNDIMAGE="SITE_74.png" SITECULTURE="en-US"/>
<BANNERS/>
<HEADER/>
<LINKS>
</LINKS>

Comment: no, where's the XML header from the file? (if it doesn't have one, it's NOT XML).

Comment: Thank u very much for the replay and sorry for the delay here is the xml<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PageDataEntity xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><PAGE CUSTOMIZE="False"> <CONTENT> <DATA> <SITEINFO BACKGROUNDIMAGE="SITE_74.png" SITECULTURE="en-US"/> <BANNERS/> <HEADER/> <LINKS> </LINKS>

Comment: okay, so it's UTF-8.  Please add your download code to your example.  also add the code that is displaying the output wrong.